# Find button in bindingNavigator c#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

I'm working in a c# windows application with vs2010 and a local database with a table named "clients".In one of my forms, I'm using a bindingNavigator in order to edit and show the entries of this table.

I would like to be able to create a "Find" button (combined with a textbox) in order to be able to go to any record by inserting the database field of the id (something like the find function in the report viewer). Is this possible and how? Thanks in advance

Comment: something like this could work but it isn't .                                                              int pos = this.clientBindingSource.Find("id", toolStripTextBox1.Text);
this.clientBindingSource.Position = pos;

Comment: actually this was my mistake, it's working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by creating a button and a textbox in binding navigator and on click event i wrote:

```
int pos = this.clientBindingSource.Find("id", toolStripTextBox1.Text); 
this.clientBindingSource.Position = pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a helpful example for someone performing a search in a similar way that want's a form dialog option:

```
        private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Objects to append to the Search form
        Form searchForm = new Form();
        Label searchLabel = new Label();
        TextBox searchBox = new TextBox();
        Button okSearchButton = new Button();
        Button cancelSearchButton = new Button();

        //Properties
        searchForm.Text = "Search";
        searchLabel.Text = "Search For:";
        searchBox.Text = "";
        okSearchButton.Text = "Search";
        cancelSearchButton.Text = "Cancel";

        //Button actions
        cancelSearchButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        okSearchButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
        searchForm.CancelButton = cancelSearchButton;
        searchForm.AcceptButton = okSearchButton;

        //Form control placement
        searchLabel.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
        searchBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
        okSearchButton.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
        cancelSearchButton.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);

        searchLabel.AutoSize = true;
        searchBox.Anchor = searchBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
        okSearchButton.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
        cancelSearchButton.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

        //Set form properties
        searchForm.ClientSize = new Size(400, 110);
        searchForm.MinimizeBox = false;
        searchForm.MaximizeBox = false;

        //Add controls to the form
        Control[] formControl = new Control[] { searchLabel, searchBox, okSearchButton, cancelSearchButton };
        searchForm.Controls.AddRange(formControl);

        //Show the form
        DialogResult dialogResult = searchForm.ShowDialog();

        if (searchForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int pos = tableNameTestBindingSource.Find("LastName", searchBox.Text);
            tableNameTestBindingSource.Position = pos;
        }
    }
```